# Syntax error in Eclipse when using static getNames method of JSONObject Java class

Tags: java, eclipse, json, static-methods

I'm trying to return all of the names that have been provided to a JSONObject class (as in, all of the keys in their own array, without their associated values). My code is currently as follows:

```
String names[] = new String[10];
names = JSONObject.getNames(jsonObj);
```

The method I'm trying to get the array from is this:

```
public static String[] getNames(JSONObject jo) {
    int length = jo.length();
    if (length == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    Iterator iterator = jo.keys();
    String[] names = new String[length];
    int i = 0;
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        names[i] = (String)iterator.next();
        i += 1;
    }
    return names;
}
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
The method getNames(JSONObject) is undefined for the type JSONObject
```

However, if I set my code to deliberately return and assign it to a variable of the wrong type:

```
int inames = JSONObject.getNames(jsonObj);
```

Highlighting either the JSONObject part or the jsonObj parameter of that above line cause Eclipse to display the following error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from String[] to int
```

Whereas highlighting the getNames method still provides the same error as before.

What am I to garner from this? Eclipse seems to know that the method is there, since it knows its correct return type, yet it's claiming that the method is undefined in the class.

Comment: Side advise #1: names array doesn't need to be pre-initialized. You could do String[] names = XXX.getNames(jsonObj) directly. Or you could simply not assign any value in the declaration (line 1).

Comment: Side advise #2: you can use `i++;` to increment variables. Your code is ok. It's just shorter.

Comment: Side advise #3: Why bother to return null if there are no attributes? I should simply return an empty array (new String[0]). You can do it simply by removing the special check and let the rest of the code do the rest (the array creates with size 0, the iterator never says hasNext true, etc)

Comment: 1. Cheers, you're right. That was a little overkill.

2 & 3. The getNames method (or the class containing it) isn't my code. It's from json.org, I got it to ease the process of parsing the text.

Comment: Ups, your last sentence (Eclipse seems to know...) invalidates my answer :)

Comment: Try pressing F3 (or ctrl+click) over the JSONObject type in your invocation. It will jump into the implementation Eclipse is using. Maybe it has something to do with classpath as @Kurt suggested.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, that results in Eclipse's class file editor claiming that JSONObject.class's source has not been found. Don't see that meaning too much, though. It claims that same thing when I click "LinkedHashMap" in a perfectly fine line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classes that I was making use of were in a separate package when I was having my problem. Moving all of JSON classes into same package as the classes I wrote and removing the package import

```
import org.json.*;
```

resolved it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that method `getNames` is not a static method *of JSONObject*. Am I right?

Inside which class is it declared?

If it's class `X` you should do:

```
X.getNames(jsonObj);
```

Comment: getNames is a public, static method. I should be able to access it through its class name.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you don't have 2 jar-files on your classpath containing a class named JSONObject?

Comment: Positive. These files are only part of this project in the form of their .java files in a separate package.